# Prove $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ to be convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

As the title suggests, I need to prove that the said sequence is convergent. I already assume that it should converge towards 0(it is said to be a real sequence, obviously) but I don't quite know how to perform the epsilon argument. Note: I need to prove it via the core definition of convergence, limit theorems are not allowed.

Comment: have you tried rationalize the numerator?

Comment: Well I can't quite wrap my head around of it because of the roots.

Comment: Can you prove $a_n<1/\sqrt n$?

Comment: After all you will get $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Do you know about Cauchy sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every bounded monotonic sequence is convergent.

1) $a_n =\sqrt{n+1} -√n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$,

is monotonically decreasing.

Consider:

$f(x) =(x+1)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}$,  $x>0.$

$f'(x) = (1/2)(x+1)^{-1/2} -(1/2)x^{-1/2} <0.$

Hence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing.

Lower bound :

Consider:

$n+1 > n ;$  then $\sqrt{n+1} >√n, $

since $g(x)= x^{1/2}$ is strictly increasing.

$\rightarrow$:

$a_n \gt 0.$

$(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 1n}-\sqrt{1}\right)=\underbrace{\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n}}}_{\to 0}\times\underbrace{\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\frac 1n}-\sqrt{1}}{\frac 1n}}_{\to(\sqrt{x})'_{x=1}=\frac 12}\to 0$

$\require{cancel}\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\left((1+\frac 1n)^{\frac 12}-1\right)=\sqrt{n}(\cancel{1}+\frac 1{2n}-\cancel{1}+o(\frac 1n))=\frac 1{2\sqrt{n}}+o(\frac 1{\sqrt{n}})\to 0$

$0\le\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\le\dfrac 1{2\sqrt{n}}\to 0$

$\displaystyle 0\le\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\int_n^{n+1}\dfrac{\mathop{dt}}{2\sqrt{t}}\le\int_n^{n+1}\dfrac{\mathop{dt}}{2\sqrt{n}}\le\dfrac{(n+1-n)}{2\sqrt{n}}\le\dfrac 1{2\sqrt{n}}\to 0$

Comment: +1 but I sugggest ordering from simpler to harder (for those who don’t  know derivatives, don’t know integrals, or don’t know Taylor expansion with small remainder).